# Rails: Deploy multiple databases to github actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, continuous-integration, github-actions, continuous-delivery

Since multiple databases is still a relatively fresh topic on Rails I wasn't able to find good resources on how to integrate them with my github actions. As long as I had single database in my app those configs we correct:

```
name: CI
on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  test:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    services:
      postgres:
        image: postgres:11
        env:
          POSTGRES_USER: postgres
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: root
          POSTGRES_DB: db_test
        ports: ['5432:5432']
        options: >-
          --health-cmd pg_isready
          --health-interval 10s
          --health-timeout 5s
          --health-retries 5
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Set up Ruby 2.6
      uses: actions/setup-ruby@v1
      with:
        ruby-version: 2.6.x
    - name: Build and test with Rake
      env:
        PGHOST: 127.0.0.1
        PGUSER: postgres
        PGPASSWORD: root
        RAILS_ENV: test
      run: |
        sudo apt-get -yqq install libpq-dev
        gem install bundler
        bundle install --jobs 4 --retry 3
        bundle exec rake db:test:prepare
        bundle exec rails test
```

However after implementing a second db I got this error:

> TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into String
> /opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/2.6.6/x64/bin/bundle:23:in `load' /opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/2.6.6/x64/bin/bundle:23:in` ' Tasks:
> TOP => db:test:load => db:test:purge (See full trace by running task
> with --trace) Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

I'm almost 100% positive that this error is related to the lack of credentials for the second db in my github action file. How can I fix it and include both my dbs there?